# ArangoDb .Net driver performance

Tags: arangodb

I am trying on the new ArangoDb-Net reimplement driver https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/tree/reimplement. Today is the first time I tried on the performance. When I used the araongosh to perform the insert. It can insert about 5000 records per second. However, when I used the .Net driver to perform the same update. I took about 2 minutes to perform the same insertion. May I know what I have done wrong? Thanks.

[EDIT] completing the question [with the github discussion](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/issues/10#issuecomment-176200092)
I have tested the code below with my arangosh

```
count=1;
startTime=+new Date();
console.log(startTime);
while(count <= 10000)
{
db.someCollection.save({"Id":"1234567890123456789012345678901234",
            "Key":1234567,
            "Revision":1234567,
            "Name":"Mohamad Abu Bakar",
            "IC Number":"1234567-12-3444",
            "Department":"IT Department",
            "Height":1234,
            "DateOfBirth":"2015-01-27 03:33",
            "Salary":3333});
    count++;
}
endTime=+new Date();
console.log(endTime);
console.log("Total time taken:" + (endTime - startTime)/1000);
```

It took 3.375 seconds to complete the operation.

I do the similar thing with the .Net driver and it took almost 9.5797819. Almost triple of the arangosh. Here's the code in .Net:

```
public static void TestArangoDb()
{
    //ASettings.AddConnection("_system", "127.0.0.1", 8529, false, "_system");
    //var db = new ADatabase("_system");
    //db.Create("trial_sample");

    ASettings.AddConnection("trial_sample",
                           "127.0.0.1", 8529, false, "trial_sample");
    var db2 = new ADatabase("trial_sample");

    db2.Collection.Create("someCollection");

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + startTime.ToLongTimeString());

    for(int count=1; count <= 10000; count++)
    {
        var employee = new Employee();
        employee.Id = "1234567890123456789012345678901234";
        employee.Key = "1234567";
        employee.Revision = "1234567";
        employee.Name = "Mohamad Abu Bakar";
        employee.IcNumber = "1234567-12-3444";
        employee.Department = "IT Department";
        employee.Height = 1234;
        employee.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2015, 1, 27, 3, 33, 3);
        employee.Salary = 3333;
        var result = db2.Document.Create<Employee>("someCollection", employee);

        //var updateDocument = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        //    .String("DocumentId", "SomeId");
        //db2.Document.Update(result.Value.String("_id"), updateDocument);
    }

    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan duration = endTime - startTime;
    Console.WriteLine("End Time: " + endTime.ToLongTimeString());
    Console.WriteLine("Total time taken: " + duration.TotalSeconds);
}

public class Employee 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IcNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

If I remove the comment for:

```
var updateDocument = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    .String("DocumentId", "SomeId");

db2.Document.Update(result.Value.String("_id"), updateDocument);
```

The performance is almost 30 times. It took 99.8789133 seconds to complete. In fact, I just perform additional update to add additional column.

Could you suggest on the problem on the code above? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide example of the data you insert through driver? How many insertions were performed in 2 minutes? This might be a longer  discussion so I would suggest to discuss it on ArangoDB google groups and once the problem is solved, answer will be posted here.

Comment: Sure. I shall post my question inside google group.

Comment: Could you post the link to the google group topic so we can look at the discussion in addition to the final answer on this site?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I could not find a topic on the google groups

Comment: Its probably a question of how many Requests arangosh does for this; maybe Wireshark can tell you more? Since this there has been no recent feedback, is this still an issue?

Comment: I've modified this to contain all the information available and the solution that finally came out.

Answer (score 2):

[yojimbo87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217288/yojimbo87) researched the issue deeper. Testing The different layers uncovered the problem.

Merge request #32 improves performance when creating, updating and replacing documents/edges from generic objects by ~57%.

On local machine single document creation with given Employee example object now takes on average ~0.4ms in 10k iteration loop using the driver. Raw .NET HTTP request (without any ArangoDB driver abstraction) takes ~0.35ms in 10k loop. Difference is made by conversion from generic object into Dictionary which needs to be done because of attributes processing (such as IgnoreField, IgnoreNullValue and AliasField).

The [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArangoDB-NET/) was updated to reflect this improvement.